# How to run fork saga after receiving data from other sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I've been trying to implement axios interceptor with redux saga. Here is how my interceptor looks like currently

```
const getLocation = ({user}) => user.locationId;
const getToken = ({auth}) => auth.token;

export function* configInterseptors() {
  const locationId = yield select(getLocation);
  const token = yield select(getToken);

  axiosAPI.interceptors.request.use(
    async (req) => {
      req.headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'X-Merchant-Location': `${!!locationId ? locationId : ''}`
      };

      return req;
    },
    (error) => {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
}
```

And here is my root saga

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield fork(configInterseptors);
  yield all([yield takeEvery(getUserData, getUserDataSaga)]); //Gets token 
  yield all([yield takeEvery(getLocationData, getUsersLocationsSaga)]); //Gets location ID
}
```

The problem is that locationId and token is always undefined in the interceptor, even though I receive the data from the server all right. How can I run configInterseptors after I've received locationId and token?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forking, hook up the `configureInterseptors` saga to the success actions of the token and locationId sagas and if both exist then configure the interceptors:

```
// in your root saga, with the correct action constants for when data is fetched successfully
yield takeEvery([GET_USER_DATA_SUCCESS, GET_LOCATION_DATA_SUCCESS], configInterseptors);
```

And then modify `configInterseptors` to exit early if either the `locationId` or `token` is missing so that it doesn't matter which order those sagas run in:

```
export function* configInterseptors() {
  const locationId = yield select(getLocation);
  const token = yield select(getToken);
  if (!(locationId && token)) {
    return;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: getUserData and getLocationData seem to be throwing unauthorized errors in this case

Comment: So the auth token must be coming from some other request if it's required to make the user and location requests. I would separate your interceptors in that case and add the auth header when you get an auth token (or at startup if you're persisting it somewhere) and add the location header in a different interceptor when the location data saga succeeds.